# How to show an org-table from another file?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have a `refcards.org` file where I store and maintain tens of tables (each having a specific name, e.g. `#+name: key-somename`).

I would like to mention and show these tables in some other org files that I am writing.

Let say I'm writing within `explanations.org` file located in `~/Path2/`, and I want to show `key-somename` table from `~/Path1/refcards.org`

How could I do that?

Comment: A link? `[[file:refcards.org::key-somename][My table]]`

Comment: `[[file:~/Path1/refcards.org::key-somename][My table]]` doesn't show a table, it shows a link.

Comment: Of course - and when you click the link you get to the table. The question was: is that enough? Or do you really need to see the table in the file?

Comment: Currently, I have to do manual copy pastes each time the source is updated.

Comment: That's the advantage of the link. I take it you are copying because you are exporting the document to some other format? It's probably not very difficult to write a function to copy the table to the current buffer: essentially following the link to where the table is and doing some `org-element` manipulation to grab a copy of the table that can be inserted into the current buffer.

Comment: Indeed all these org files are exported. If the solution would be to write a function that would take the PATH of the source file and the NAME of the table as arguments. I guess it would be less tedious than a manual copy paste. Still, I'd have to execute the function at each part of `explanation.org` where source tables have been modified for every modification wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, although you could bind it to a key to make it less onerous. What you are really looking for, I guess, is a modified `#+INCLUDE` that includes a table from a file, instead of the whole file, at that point. But that is a biggger change. You might want to propose it as a feature request on the Org Mode mailing list. It might not be implemented, but people might have additional ideas.

Comment: `#+INCLUDE` worked LOL, so you found the solution, thanks a lot! Do you want to answer the question or shall I do it?

Comment: Well, that was a lucky shot :-) I didn't realize that `#+INCLUDE` can include named elements. +1 for the question! Live and learn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#+INCLUDE` mechanism can be used not only to include a file, but also portions of the file (specified by beginning and ending line numbers), and more importantly for this question, headlines and *named elements*. See the `Include Files` section of the manual with `C-h i g(org)<RET> m Include<TAB><RET>`.

So one can say:

```
#+INCLUDE: "~/Path1/refcards.org::key-somename"
```

and get the named element (the table in this case) included from the `refcards.org` file.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`org-transclusion`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org-transclusion.html) library.

See [**`org-transclusion`:     *Transclude text content via links***](https://github.com/nobiot/org-transclusion), and also [`org-transclusion` MANUAL](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/doc/org-transclusion.html)

---

To get this

[image: Demo of transclusion-mode]

Do this

1. `M-x package-refresh-contents RET`, and `M-x package-install RET`  [`org-transclusion`](https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/org-transclusion.html) `RET`.
2. `emacs -Q`.  `M-x package-initialize`, and optionally put this snippet in your `*scratch*` and do `M-x eval-buffer`.

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 '(org-transclusion-fringe
   ((t
     (:background "orange"))))
 '(org-transclusion-source-fringe
   ((t
     (:background "green")))))
```

2. Create a file with `explanations.org` with following content

```
** Animals

These creatures you are domesticated.

#+transclude: [[./refcards.org::animals]]

** Birds

These creatures fly.

#+transclude: [[./refcards.org::birds]]

** Insects

These creatures are a nuisance.

#+transclude: [[./refcards.org::insects]]
```

4. Create a file `refcards.org` with following content

```
#+CAPTION: Animals
#+NAME: animals
| Cat | Dog     |
| Cow | Buffalo |

#+CAPTION: Birds
#+NAME: birds
| Crow    | Pigeon |
| Peacock | Eagle  |


#+CAPTION: Insects
#+NAME: insects
| Cockroach | Grasshopper |
| Mosquito  | Housefly    |
```

5. `C-x C-f explanations.org`, and do `M-x org-transclusion-mode RET`.
6. This is what you will see.

[image: Demo of transclusion-mode]

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about `org-transclusion`, the package looks great!